# Wrapping specific checked exception in domain unchecked ones?

Tags: java, programming-practices, exceptions, exception-handling

Uncle Bob says in Clean Code book that Unchecked Exceptions should be used. Now JDK has some checked exceptions: IOException, IllegalAccessException etc. which cannot be avoided.

In my application logic suppose I have an exception:

```
public class MyDomainException extends RunntimeException {
    public MyDomainException(Exception e) {
         super(e);
    }
    //etc
}
```

And some code

```
try {
    outputStream.write(someBytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new MyDomainException(e);
}
```

Is this a good approach or should these checked exception be propagated up the ladder and filling the method signatures?

*Edit: I understand this was asked and answered.*

Can MyDomainException be used for business logic validation too or this exception should only be used for wrapping and other exception(s) should handle the business logic?

*Edit: I would still like an answer to this question.*

Comment: What about the second question? Should I open another question or can this be reopened / edited?

Comment: Yes. Edit the second question out of this post and ask a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good style. For example Spring's JdbcTemplate makes the same with JDBC exceptions.

From Spring documentation:

> It(JdbcTemplate) also catches JDBC exceptions and translates them to the generic, more informative, exception hierarchy defined in the org.springframework.dao package.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, I understand Uncle's Bob's philosophy on this, but sometimes you *want* to capture the CheckedException and deal with it there and then.  The example you use of catching, wrapping and throwing is fine, especially under Java 7 which does a better job of maintaining the hierarchy of exceptions.